# Cannot read property 'posts' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get this.state.posts in the render section, but it's throwing an error `Cannot read property 'posts' of null` Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Blog extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/emma.wordpress.com/posts"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ posts: res.data.posts });
        console.log("setState: ", this.state.posts);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <ul>
          {Object.values(this.state.posts).map((post) => {
            return <li>{post.name}</li>;
          })}
          ;
        </ul>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch/axios function takes time.
so basically you try to map over posts that not yet exist.

```js
class Blog extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(){
this.state = {
posts: []
}
}
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/emma.wordpress.com/posts"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ posts: res.data.posts });
        console.log("setState: ", this.state.posts);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <ul>
          {Object.values(this.state.posts).map((post) => {
            return <li>{post.name}</li>;
          })}
          ;
        </ul>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Now, you will map over an empty array until you put there some values.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `state` in your code, please define it like

```
class Blog extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {posts: []};

  componentDidMount() {...}

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `posts` state first. In React when a component mounts

1. states are initialized,
2. then the DOM prints
3. then lifecycle hook runs
4. then updates the state
5. DOM update with latest state

in your code you haven't define the state. that's why you are getting the error.